# I added a Prescription Field in my Magento 1.9 Form Page

Tags: magento-1.9, api, database-schema

```
$fieldset->addField('prescription', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('surgery')->__('Upload'),
          //'value'  => 'Upload',
          'name' => 'prescription',
          'required'  => true,
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => true
        ));
```

I have added code for adding or Uploading a Prescription File....But after uploading the Prescription File...The File is not getting saved in the Database on clicking the Save Button....Any possible solutions please reply back to this post....

Comment: How do you getting file in save action.?Can you share the code.

Comment: Below is the Code...$fieldset->addField('prescription', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('surgery')->__('Upload'),
          //'value'  => 'Upload',
    'name' => 'prescription',
          'required'  => true,
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => true
        ));

Comment: Remove command line and then share the code. Command line creating confusion in that code.

Comment: Heyy Nagaraj , I have mentioned the Code above in a structured format....Please have a look at it...

Comment: I have to change the button label of the Upload Prescription Field...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your file in server while uploading file in admin form,use the following code in **saveAction()**

> ```
> $uploadFilename = pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
> $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
> $fileName = $uploadFilename.".".$extension;
> $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('prescription');
> // Any extention would work
> //$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
> $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('csv', 'CSV'));
> $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
> $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
>
> // We set media as the upload dir
> $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
> $_newfile=$uploader->save($path, $fileName);
> ```

Thank  you..